# C#でJArrayのキーに特定の文字列が含まれているか調べる方法

Tags: c#, json

C#初心者です。
古いバージョンですが、C#の.NET Standard 2.0を使用しています。
JSONを以下のようにParseして、Keyに"test1"や"names"が含まれているかを調べたいのですが、どうすればいいのかわかりません。以下の例ではうまく出力されませんでした。

Parse自体はうまく行っており、`parsedJson[0]["test1"]["names"][0].Value<string>()` の中身は”aaa”と出力されました。

キーに特定の文字列が含まれているかどうか判定する場合、どのようにすれば良いか、わかる方がいたら教えてください。

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System;

JArray parsedJson = JArray.Parse(@"[{""test1"":{""names"":[""aaa"",""bbb""]}},{""test2"":{""test"":[""ccc"",""ddd""]}}]");
if(parsedJson[0].Contains(new JValue("test1")))
{
    if(parsedJson[0]["test1"].Contains(new JValue("names")))
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(parsedJson[0]["test1"]["names"][0].Value<string>());
    }
}
```

Comment: この記事あたりを試してみてください。[JArray - search for an object by key name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52009930/9014308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONには型情報がないため、配列の先頭要素がディクショナリ（JSONオブジェクト）型であるかのテスト・型変換が必要です。[`as`演算子](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator)を使用すると型変換を試み、成功すればその値が、失敗すれば`null`が得られる仕組みになっています。

```
var array0 = parsedJson[0] as JObject;
```

`JObject`に`test1`のキーが存在するかは[`JObject.TryGetValue`メソッド](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_TryGetValue.htm)が用意されています。存在すればその値が、存在しない場合は`null`が返されます。

```
JToken test1Token;
array0.TryGetValue("test1", out test1Token)
```

これらを組み合わせたコード全体は

```
var array0 = parsedJson[0] as JObject;
JToken test1Token;
if (array0 != null && array0.TryGetValue("test1", out test1Token)) {
    var test1 = test1Token as JObject;
    JToken namesToken;
    if (test1 != null && test1.TryGetValue("names", out namesToken)) {
        var names = namesToken as JArray;
        if (names != null)
            Console.WriteLine(names[0]);
    }
}
```

---

なお、[C# 7.0で機能強化](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7)が行われており、よりシンプルに記述できるようになっています。.NET Standard 2.0の場合、C# 7.3が使われるため以下の機能は使用可能です。

```
if (parsedJson[0] is JObject array0 && array0.TryGetValue("test1", out var test1Token)) {
    if (test1Token is JObject test1 && test1.TryGetValue("names", out var namesToken)) {
        if (namesToken is JArray names)
            Console.WriteLine(names[0]);
    }
}
```

---

なお、[.NET Core 3.0以降では`System.Text.Json`が導入](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview)されています。その上で.NET Standard 2.0向けに[NuGetパッケージ`System.Text.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json)としてバックポートされています。こちらが標準機能ですので、可能であれば移行しておくことをお勧めします。

```
using (var json = JsonDocument.Parse(@"[{""test1"":{""names"":[""aaa"",""bbb""]}},{""test2"":{""test"":[""ccc"",""ddd""]}}]")) {
    var parsedJson = json.RootElement;
    if (parsedJson.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array) {
        var array0 = parsedJson[0];
        if (array0.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Object && array0.TryGetProperty("test1", out var test1)) {
            if (test1.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Object && test1.TryGetProperty("names", out var names)) {
                if (names.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array)
                    Console.WriteLine(names[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: とても丁寧にご解説頂きありがとうございます。無事実装することが出来ました！